# batch update ,txt file names with the third line content (3rd line within)

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, batch-rename

I have managed to form a regex to search for a date format found within the `.txt` files and batch update each name of the `.txt` file with each date found within. However, a new requirement to get member ID and member name, before the date has arisen.

---

*I'm reluctant to use a regex for this as the format doesn't seem unique enough. I **was thinking grab everything on 'line 3' of text file, and prepend to name (before date).***

---

**For instance the first 3 lines of the .txt files look like below:**

```
MEMBER    
-------- ---------------
9999199  RON, CAPTAIN // this is line 3
```

**i.e. Desired new file name/output:** `9999199_RON,CAPTAIN_2015-07-09.txt`

Below is what I have thus far that batches through text files in a directory and grabs date as name. (*i.e.* currently renames as `2015-07-09.txt`) .. Just need to get the Member number and the name that follows above (including the comma as well) to prepend to new name - or put as new file name before the date aspect.

---

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

let dir = './'

fs.readdir(dir, {
  encoding: 'utf8',
  withFileTypes: true
}, (err, files) => {
  if (err) {
    // Error happened when reading the directory
    console.error(err)
    return
  }
  for (const file of files) {
    if (!file.isFile()) {
      // Directory or block device?
      continue;
    }

    // Read file contents
    let fileContents = fs.readFileSync(path.join(dir, file.name), 'utf8')
    let dateMatches = fileContents.match(/[12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])/)
    if (dateMatches) {
      // There is a date here
      fs.rename(path.join(dir, file.name), path.join(dir, dateMatches[0]), (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err)
          // Do your error handling stuff here...

          return
        } else {
          console.log('Renamed', file.name, 'to', dateMatches[0])
        }
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: `I was thinking grab everything on 'line 3' of text file, and prepend to name`, did it work for you?

Comment: No, I have not figured out how to extract by line yet.. (hence the question on this part) Only have figured out regex at this point (i.e. my working date). But don't want to use regex for these two things because their patterns don't seem unique, seems unstable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try splitting `fileContents` with the delimiter `\n`, and limit it to `3` chunks.

```
let [,,line3] = fileContents.split('\n', 3); 

if(line3) {
    // do the work
} else {
    // error handling, where file is too short, less than 3 lines.
}
```

Then you can do further `replace()` or `split()` / `join()` on `line3`